# Filling an array of pointers, deleting when exiting

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In C++, Lets say I'm creating an array of pointers and each element should point to a data type MyType. I want to fill this array in a function `fillArPtr(MyType *arPtr[])`. Lets also say I can create MyType objects with a function `createObject(int x)`. It works the following way:

```
MyType *arptr[10]; // Before there was a mistake, it was written: "int *arptr[10]"
void fillArPtr(MyType *arptr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        MyType myObject = createObject(i);
        arptr[i] = new MyType(myobject);
    }
}
```

Is it the best way to do it? In this program how should I use delete to delete objects created by "new" (or should I use delete at all?)

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry for mistake of course it is `MyType *arptr[10]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    delete arptr[i];
    arptr[i] = 0;
}
```

I suggest you look into boost `shared_ptr` (also in TR1 library)

Much better already:

```
 std::vector<MyType*> vec;
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    vec.push_back(new MyType(createObject(i));

 // do stuff

 // cleanup:
 while (!vec.empty())
 {
     delete (vec.back());
     vec.pop_back();
 }
```

Shooting for the stars:

```
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyType> ptr_t;
 std::vector<ptr_t> vec;
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    vec.push_back(ptr_t(new MyType(createObject(i)));
```

Comment: you don't need to check for `NULL` before deleting

Comment: How about suggesting `vector` or `array` before moving on to shared pointers! :-)

Comment: and boost has [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) which might be more appropriate than `shard_ptr`

Comment: `delete NULL;` is perfectly valid and legal, so it doesn't matter what's happened in the mean time. If the pointer has been left dangling testing for `NULL` won't help at all. So `if (x) delete x;` is just clutter.

Comment: Added vector suggestion. @awoodland: thanks for the hint I forget about that library all the time

Comment: I like how a clearly green C++ programmer is now going to be diving into boost shared pointers...  this may be a bad thing if the OP is for example a student.  I can just see an exam question "allocate an array of pointers to objects of type T, then correctly free the memory".  Solution: use boost::shared_ptr<T>  :)   Grade: F?  A?

Comment: @wallacer: Hard to please the crowd. I've aded an 'intermediate' example. It _IS_ c++ so I assume a vector is warranted.

Comment: @sehe  I wasn't criticizing.  I just think it's hilarious! :)  pointers?  use boost.  solved....  personally i don't use boost much, but i can see the appeal

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked "What is the best way", let me go out on a limb here and suggest a more C++-like alternative. Since your `createObject` is already returning objects by value, the following should work:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<MyType> fillArray()
{
  std::vector<MyType> res;
  for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    res.push_back(createObject(i));
  return res;
}
```

Now you don't need to do any memory management at all, as allocation and clean-up is done by the vector class. Use it like this:

```
std::vector<MyType> myArr = fillArray();
someOtherFunction(myArr[2]);   // etc.
someLegacyFunction(&myArr[4]); // suppose it's "void someLegacyFunction(MyType*)"
```

Do say if you have a genuine requirement for manual memory management and for pointers, though, but preferably with a usage example.

Comment: in cases where you know (or can guess at) the size of the vector beforehand, you'll get much better performance if you pre-size the vector.   std::vector<MyType> res(init_size)

Comment: @Wallacer: That incurs expensive default constructions. Preferably you'd say `res.reserve(init_size);`. Good point though.

Answer (score 1):

Your method places the array of pointers on the stack, which is fine.  Just thought I'd point out that it's also possible to store your array of pointers [on the heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/) like so.  Youd do this if you want your array to persist beyond the current scope

```
MyType **arptr = new MyType[10]; 
void fillArPtr(MyType *arptr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        MyType myObject = createObject(i);
        arptr[i] = new MyType(myobject);
    }
}
```

If you do this, don't forget to delete the array itself from the heap

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
    delete arptr[i];
}
delete [] arptr;
```

If you're going to use vector, and you know the size of the array beforehand, you should pre-size the array.  You'll get much better performance.

```
vector<MyType*> arr(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would basically go through each element of the array and call delete on it, then set the element to 0 or null.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       delete arptr[i];
       arptr[i] = 0;
   }
```

Another way to do this is with an std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of auto_ptrs if you don't have to return the array anywhere.  As long as you don't make copies of the auto_ptrs, they won't change ownership and they will deallocate their resources upon exiting of the function since its RAII based.  It's also part of the standard already, so don't need boost to use it :)  They're not useful in most places but this sounds like a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the allocated objects using `delete objPtr`. In your case,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  delete arptr[i];
  arptr[i] = 0;
}
```

The rule of thumb to remember is, if you allocate an object using `new`, you should `delete` it. If you allocate an array of objects using `new[N]`, then you must `delete[]` it.

Instead of sticking pointers into a raw array, have a look at `std::array` or `std::vector`. If you also use a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` to hold the objects within an `std::array` you don't need to worry about deleting them.

```
typedef std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyType>, 10> MyTypeArray;
MyTypeArray arptr;

for( MyTypeArray::iterator it = arptr.begin(), int i = 0; it != arptr.end(); ++it ) {
  it->reset( new MyType( createObject(i++) ) );
}
```

You don't need to worry about deleting those when you're done using them.

Is the `createObject(int x)` function using `new` to create objects and returning a pointer to this?. In that case, you need to delete that as well because in this statement

```
new MyType( createObject(i++) )
```

you're making a copy of the object returned by `createObject`, but the original is then leaked. If you change `createObject` also to return an `std::unique_ptr<MyType>` instead of a raw pointer, you can prevent the leak.

If `createObject` is creating objects on the stack and returning them by value, the above should work correctly.

If `createObject` is not using `new` to create objects, but is creating them on the stack and returning pointers to these, your program is not going to work as you want it to, because the stack object will be destroyed when `createObject` exits.